# Resize UITableviewCell when content changes

Tags: uitableview, autolayout

I have a TableViewCell with a label, a button and a hidden textfield of size 0.
If the user tapps the button the textfield should become visible. So far so good. But in console I get a constraint error during that animation because the textfield needs more space than the cell is currently sized.

How can I avoid the constraint error?

Here is my implementation:

```
func showTextField(show:Bool){

        if show{
            if textFieldHeightConstraint.constant != 200{
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4) { [weak self] in
                    self?.textFieldHeightConstraint.constant = 200
                    self?.feedbackTextView.isHidden = false
                    self?.viewModel?.refreshTableView()
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            textFieldHeightConstraint.constant = 0
            feedbackTextView?.text = "TODO"
            feedbackTextView.isHidden = true
            viewModel?.refreshTableView()
        }
    }
```

//in controller then:

```
func refreshTableView(){
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }
```

Constraint Error:

```
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000a3fa70 UITextView:0x7f8cd4073e00'TODO'.height == 200   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000a13020 V:|-(16)-[UILabel:0x7f8cd2e19130'M\U00f6chten Sie zu dieser Rec...']   (active, names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f8cd2e140d0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000a0fb10 V:[UILabel:0x7f8cd2e19130'M\U00f6chten Sie zu dieser Rec...']-(8)-[UIButton:0x7f8cd2e16ea0'Add remark']   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000a0a490 V:[UITextView:0x7f8cd4073e00'TODO']-(>=16)-|   (active, names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f8cd2e140d0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000a32440 V:[UIButton:0x7f8cd2e16ea0'Add remark']-(8)-[UITextView:0x7f8cd4073e00'TODO']   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000a484b0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f8cd2e140d0.height == 156   (active)>"
)
```

Comment: Try setting the **Priority** of `textFieldHeightConstraint` to `999`

Comment: exactly! thank you :)